# Get earliest date as Start date and latest date as end date

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I Have a requirement where I need to get earliest date as start date and If latest date is present then I need to have it as end date, if latest date is blanks which means the person is still active then I need to have it as blanks.

I used Min and Max on date fields but My latest date field is not capturing as Blanks if date is absent.

[image]

Comment: An Date field does not allow to be '', just NULL. So it should never be able to be blank?

Comment: It's end date for an employee, So imagine you were working in an organization you left it and joined back, what will be the end date populated for such fields for second record?

Comment: Generally speaking, corporations dont all do it in the same way. But some simply remove the "delete flag" and reactivate the user, while some like to have a clear record of them all having a new record per hire - meaning that 1 single employee could theoretically be in the table for each time he joined and left the company. At that point, all you need to do is show the latest start_date record of said employee to get the current session. That is kind of what my answer does.

Comment: The data is little tricky here, can't explain the exact business problem, but the above explanation, of employee rejoining is exact replica of my problem statement, and the table do accepts duplicate entries and null date values.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did my answer not work with your case, and what differed?

Comment: It do worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(start_date) Start_Date, 
    NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(end_date,'29991231')), '29991231') End_Date
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5febc25e9c79840fe6aa2e55d77cf5d0

At least it will *seem* to give the right results based on the sample data available. However, this would still show a `null` if a record with an earlier start date has a `null` end date, and a record with a later start date does have an end date. It's likely this should never happen in real data, but then real data tends to be messy even when it shouldn't be.

---

To really do this properly, you need to find the *whole row* with the latest start date and then look at the end date value *from that row.* Fortunately, we have a great way to count rows: the `row_number()` windowing function:

```
SELECT ID, Start_Date, End_Date
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Start_Date, End_Date, 
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Start_Date DESC) rn
    FROM MyTable
) t0
WHERE rn=1
```

But this is only part of the solution. This should now always have the right `End_Date`, but will usually have the wrong `Start_Date`. We can update it to fix that error like this:

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT MIN(Start_Date) FROM MyTable t WHERE t.ID=t0.ID) Start_Date, End_Date
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Start_Date, End_Date, 
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Start_Date DESC) rn
    FROM MyTable
) t0
WHERE rn=1
```

And now we will **always** get the right result.

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b7d4cba4849eee9ba3bf978cebfc3bf

---

Finally, all this assumes you have a reasonable schema using `null` and `DateTime` values, and not an **unreasonable** schema using `varchar` and empty strings. If the latter really is your situation the schema design really is **BROKEN** and you should *fix it*.

This also assumes at least MySql 8.0. If you're using something older than that, condolences. 5.7 and earlier are rooted in basic design from 2006, and don't really qualify as a modern database platform.

Comment: Absolutely, I Used the Over partition by and sort the data in Desc based on Start date, and It worked

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the earliest start_date, by ID. And also bring with whatever is in the End_date field - No matter if it is NULL, or has an date. Then you can first get group by ID(which is not unique in your example given), then use MIN() on start_date. Then you fetch which row these values belong to, and thereby get the End_date. This works, but if you've got several start dates with the same ID, that complicates things - and in that case we need some more example data with a bit mor explanation of how it is supposed to work. But, here goes:

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o2NyDpAc76TLYdmGFGHqag/3

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  ID int,
  Start_Date date,
  End_date date null
);
INSERT INTO my_table (ID,Start_Date, End_date) 
VALUES 
(1,'2021-01-01', '2022-04-05'),
(1,'2022-01-01', '2022-04-02'),
(2,'2022-07-01', '2022-05-07'),
(2,'2022-01-01', null);

SELECT a.*
FROM my_table a
join (SELECT 
ID,
MIN(my_table.Start_date) as 'Start_date'
FROM my_table
GROUP BY ID) jn
on a.ID=jn.ID and a.Start_date=jn.Start_date
```

Source table:

| ID | Start_Date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2021-01-01' | '2022-04-05' |
| 1 | '2022-01-01' | 2022-04-02 |
| 2 | '2022-07-01' | '2022-05-07' |
| 2 | '2022-01-01' | NULL |

Results table:

| ID | Start_Date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2021-01-01' | '2022-04-05' |
| 2 | '2022-01-01' | NULL |

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.
can't we sort the Start date column in Desc and get the top End date record as End date,
in a join statement, I did and It worked well

Comment: Not quite following here sadly. Could you explain what you would want adjusted here in the outcome etc? :)

Comment: SELECT ID, (SELECT MIN(Start_Date) FROM MyTable t WHERE t.ID=t0.ID) Start_Date, End_Date
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Start_Date, End_Date, 
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Start_Date DESC) rn
    FROM MyTable
) t0
WHERE rn=1